# Firebase Cloud Messaging Notifications for iOS not showing opened and analytics

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, swizzling

I'am using FCM to send notifications to iOS apps. The notifications are received on the device well, but I can not get the "Opened" or "Conversion " rate in the Notification console GUI. It always shows "0 opened" and "0 Conversion" for almost 200 0000 notifications sent.

I double checked all the implementation but I can't get it working.

I have `FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled` set to `YES` in plist. I implemented all the methods listed on Firebase guides and docs.

I don't have any notification related events showing in the Firebase analytics pane either.

Comment: I chose not to setup Google Analytics, this seems to break notifications, be sure to setup Analytics.

Answer (score 6):

To enable Open count metric in Cloud Messaging > Reports, you need to mark `notification_open` event as conversion in Analytics > Events:

[image: Firebase Event as Conversion]

That's the event automatically generated by Firebase but not enabled by default.

Answer (score 0):

#### It looks like you need to do some additional [setup](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6394759?hl=en#conversion).

Conversion events
When composing a notification, it is important to think ahead and define which metric to use to assess its effectiveness. A Conversion event is an event or user action that you want to track to further measure and evaluate.

A built-in Notifications funnel analysis automatically reports Notification sent and Notification opened events. You can provide an optional conversion event that you want to analyze with the Notifications funnel analysis.

An Analytics User Property `firebase_last_notification` is automatically created when you send a notification from the Notifications console the first time. This identifies the most recent notification opened by the user, allowing proper notification attribution of the conversion events.

See [Conversion Events](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317522#enable) to learn more conversion events and steps to take to enable conversion.

Prerequisite: Make sure your app has integrated the Firebase Cloud Messaging SDK, which enables automatic reporting of these notification-related events for the funnel analysis.

---

#### Following the link to learn more about '[Conversion Events](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317522#enable)' you'll read:

Enable events as conversions
Conversions are your most important events. By designating an event as a conversion, you facilitate attribution reporting and postback capacity on that event. Additionally, conversion events are uploaded immediately by the SDK in order to make them actionable more quickly. You may add up to 10 events as conversions.

To designate an event as a conversion:

In Firebase, navigate to your app. In Analytics, click Events, then click Network Settings. In the row for the event, click the selector menu action menu (far right of the row), then click Enable conversion.
Once an event has been enabled as a conversion, it is available in ATTRIBUTION → CONVERSION EVENTS. Attribution reporting begins for that event at the time you enable it as a conversion.

To see AdWords-attributed Conversion Events in your attribution reports, import the Firebase Conversion Event to AdWords. Once you have linked your project to AdWords, then those conversion events will also be available in AdWords. You can import them under Tools → Conversions → Firebase.

Note: The VALUE event parameter supplied with conversion events must be a number, and it must be accompanied by a currency code.

Comment: Thanks Doug for the anwer but I am stuck at the initial point: I can not get the : "A built-in Notifications funnel analysis automatically reports Notification sent and Notification opened events."

Comment: From your dashboard, select analytics from the side menu, then select the "FUNNELS" tab, Create a funnel and in the events you'd like to track you will see events like: `notification_recieve` and `notification_open`

Comment: Thks Doug, I just did it and It shows 0 notification_receive and 0 notification_open on the last 90 days. Firebase support wrote to me there is a bug in the SDK version I use, I have to upgrade and call explicitlty  "appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)" method: